# What is an Empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

We define the term "Set" as,

> *A set is a collection of objects.*

And an "Empty set" as,

> *An empty set is a set which contains nothing.*

**First problem I encountered:**

*How* the definition of "Empty set" is consistent with the definition of "sets" if "Empty set" contains nothing and a "set" is a collection of objects.

Further we discovered in set theory that every set has a subset that is the Null set.

Such as,

If $A=\emptyset$ and $B=\{1,2,3\}$ then,

$$A \subset B$$

**Second problem I encountered:**

*How* and *why* "No element" is referred and considered as an element as we do in case of null set that is, when we say that every set has a subset that is the Null set?

**Third and Last one:**

*How* can a set possess "some thing" and "nothing" simultaneously that is when we say that every set (containing objects) has a subset which is Null set (contains nothing)?

Comment: A better notation for the empty set would be $\{\}$.

Comment: You often get into trouble if you try to do math based on dictionary-like definitions like these. Another example: Look up the definition of  "number" in the dictionary, then try to prove that 2+2=4 based only that defintion. It would be impossible.

Comment: Just like mathematicians found it necessary to define $0$, they have found it necessary to define the empty set $\emptyset$: For all $x$, $x\notin \emptyset$.

Comment: Note that, in ZFC set theory, we actually have $0=\emptyset$.

Comment: Relax @AlecTeal. I know this definition is an intuitive one but can't you see that question itself is also an intuitive one.  This is obvious that if the question is a sort of beginning then definitions or other details given in the question are also of beginners' level. My question is not just related to definitions but there are two more problems I encountered. What do you say about them???

Comment: @SufyanNaeem Your other two "problems" are also just misunderstandings of definitions.

Comment: What can I do? These definitions are given in the book I am following now a days that is, *College Algebra fifth edition* by *Raymond A Barnett* and *Micheal R Ziegler* If you don't believe me you can go through it. And there you will find the same definition of **Set** as I stated above.

Comment: @AlecTeal Aren't things so simple when you already have an advanced education in mathematics? Unfortunately for some mere mortals, they have yet to be educated yet and come here seeking to remedy that. A good community welcomes all honest attempts to learn.

Comment: @SufyanNaeem No one's saying they "don't believe you"; they're just saying that if you're having trouble understanding that definition (and yes, not understanding why the empty set is a valid set means you're having trouble with the definition), then you should consider some other definitions, or reconsider the definition without trying so hard to make it fit your preconceived notions based on non-mathematical language.

Comment: From the brief description of your text at Google Books, it looks like a very general introduction to some topics in algebra. In the interests of keeping things simple, they are not being as absolutely precise in their definitions as they could be -- probably a good thing at that level. They might have said, for example, that a set is a *possibly empty* collection of objects putting undue emphasis on the emptiness aspect. This approach is not an unusual compromise in texts at that level.

Comment: Just because a  concept was evident on first inspection for a few doesn't  make it unworthy of discussion. 

I want more people to feel good about talking about mathematics. You know what I hate? The artificial sense of exclusivity some of us project onto the field. I don't mind the desire to spend time intelligently; but the notion that the questions and work of amateurs are somehow getting undeserved attention simply because they are more comprehensible or are harming "real math" that I find terribly self-destructive.

Comment: Book: Introduction to Set Theory, Third Edition (Revised and Expanded) - Karel Hrbacek and Thomas Jech

Comment: I don't think there is any axiom supposing the existence of the empty set. Just an axiom to say "there exists some set". The empty set is then obtained via the separation schema.

Comment: You should be careful when you say out of loud 'We define the term Set..'. To be pedantic, there are two different set theory. 'Naive set theory': where we take for granted the concepts of Set, Element, Property (as natural object that are already in our mind and don't need to be defined). 'Axiomatic Set Theory': here we define a property to be something that can be written using the language of logic (roughly), and a set is anything that respects the established axioms.

Comment: Why can't a collection be empty? I collect stamps, but yesterday I sold all of my stamps to my brother, so today my collection is empty. Tomorrow I will buy some more, adding to my collection, so that it is no longer empty.

Comment: @KyleStrand ...or ask a very reasonable question on a math forum.

Comment: @MadeleineP.Vincent Asking isn't sufficient; carefully considering the advice and feedback given on that forum is necessary as well.

Comment: @Tom Depends what axiom schema you're using.

Comment: We do not treat Euclid's statement "A point is that which has no part" as a definition of a point. Instead, we treat it as a palliative to our intuition, to assuage the pain that a point is an undefined concept in Euclid's synthetic approach. The same holds for the statement "A set is a collection of objects".

Answer (score 77, accepted):

A shopping bag is an object to carry things; an empty bag is a bag with nothing inside it.

From the viewpoint of people trained in mathematics, the explanation "a set is a collection of objects" is formally consistent with the set being empty (in which case the set is a collection of *no* objects).

But perhaps, at first, you should just take "a set is a collection of objects" as an *informal* idea of what sets are. Apart from the empty set, that phrase also has problems with collections of objects that are not sets because they are "too big", e.g. the collection of all sets is not a set.

Moreover, most of the sets considered in set theory aren't really sets of "objects" - they are sets of *other sets*. In the commonly studied set theories, there are no objects other than sets.  This is another way that "a set is a collection of objects" can give the wrong impression.

So don't get hung up on the "a set is a collection of objects" phrase. Once you spend some time working with sets, you will have a better sense of what they are and how they work.

Comment: FWIW, most of the sets considered in other branches of mathematics _do_ contain objects that are themselves not described as sets (though it might be possible to express them equivalently as sets).

Comment: But since everything inherits from Object, a set must be an object.....oh sorry, I let my Java get in the way :)

Comment: @SufyanNaeem If the analogy of "a bag is still a bag even when it's not holding anything" doesn't help, I'm not sure what *will* help. It's unclear what is actually causing the confusion here, since your question simply says that the definition appears to contradict particular examples, but the shopping bag example shows why the definition *isn't* contradictory.

Comment: @SufyanNaeem I think my response holds even if you replace "help" with "help much." In any case, in my answer, I did my best to provide comprehensive answers to each of your questions; did that help at all?

Comment: I think it's clearer to describe the empty set as "a collection of zero objects" than "a collection of no objects". "Zero" makes it clear that you're counting the number of objects in the collection, whereas "a collection of no objects" sounds like a negation of the definition which is, I think, the source of the confusion.

Comment: @ruakh I guess so, but "bag of shopping" strikes my ears as something like a D&D-ism, and the noun usage of "shopping" seems a bit slippery. A bag *for* shopping is still a bag for shopping even when no shopping has yet been done with it.

Comment: @KyleStrand: Re: "the noun usage of 'shopping' seems a bit slippery": I'm not sure of its distribution in terms of dialect, register, and so on, but it definitely exists. (If you Google "put away the shopping", you'll find quite a few examples.) But yeah, now you have me wondering if a bag can be a "bag of holding" if it contains no holding. :-P

Comment: @ruakh I say "slippery" not because it's "incorrect" English, but because the implied analogy to formal mathematical concepts makes no sense due to the multiplicity of meanings involved. If "shopping" means both the action of shopping and the items acquired while shopping, then it's not actually parallel to "groceries" or "holding", since "groceries" only means *items* and "holding" (in the D&D sense) only means the *action* of holding.

Comment: The confusion of "how can a bag of shopping not hold any shopping" only (or at least primarily) exists because "hold any shopping" implies that the *items* usage, while "bag of shopping" could mean either usage. Hence why I clarified in my first response to you that a bag *for* shopping (the action usage) is *always* a bag *for* shopping, *regardless* of its contents. (Even if "for shopping" is taken to mean *for holding shopping items*!)

Comment: @KyleStrand: I see what you're saying, but I think you're understating the relevance of immibis' comment. In real life, a "bag of groceries" or "cup of tea" is a bag that currently contains some groceries or a cup that currently contains some tea; but in math, something like (for example) "Let *S* be a set of real numbers" does *not* rule out *S* = ∅. So although the 'set:container::element:contained-item' analogy is better than the 'set:multiple-items::element:one-item' analogy, it doesn't totally solve the problem. The only total solution is formalism (or at least convention).

Comment: @ruakh: I did not write "a bag of groceries" or a "bag of shopping". I wrote a "shopping bag" and an "empty bag", i.e. an empty shopping bag. A "shopping bag" is just a kind of bag, it is not a "bag of shopping", and I chose my terms carefully. I could remove the word "shopping" entirely from my answer, and the point would remain the same.

Comment: @CarlMummert: Sure. But mathematicians usually write "a set of real numbers", not "a real number set". (Don't get me wrong; I think your answer is a good one. The first paragraph, despite its limitations, may help the OP get past his/her hangup; and the rest of the answer thoroughly compensates for the limitations of the first paragraph.)

Comment: @BrianJ Of course a set is an object. Followup: Consider the set of "all sets that don't contain themselves". Does your mind throw an Exception when you try to figure out whether the set contains itself?

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Yeah....that seems like a bit of a paradox.  It can't contain itself, which means it has to contain itself.

Comment: @ruakh What CarlMummert said. Except that I would add that "<X> of real numbers" is terminologically more akin to "grocery <x>" than "<x> of groceries", despite the phrasing.

Comment: @BrianJ That's actually one of the most famous paradoxes in the development of set theory.

Answer (score 29):

In addition to the answer by Carl, there's a **big difference** between having the empty set as a *member* $\emptyset \in A$ and having the empty set as a *subset* $\emptyset \subset A$. I think you are confusing the two concepts.

From a set $A$ we can create a subset by "picking out" elements of $A$. Now, if we don't pick out anything, we're left with the nothingness we started with, $\emptyset$. It was not a member of $A$, it's another set.

Now, with for example $B = \{ \emptyset, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{a,b\} \}$, we do have that the empty set is a member of $B$. This $B$ could be the set of all subsets of $C = \{a,b\}$, and one of those subsets would be the empty set, as we said before.

Comment: Just as there is a differne between putting a *bag* (and its content) into another bag or putting the *contents* of the first bag into the second. (Car Mummert's shopping bag analogy is just to good)

Answer (score 13):

My usual advice to students that have some hard time in introductory to set theory, is to work with the formal definitions until they develop some intuition.

So I strongly suggest that if you're unclear as to what is the empty set, and what sort of concept it is, you'll sit down and work with its formal definition.

> **Definition.** We say that a set $A$ is empty, if $\forall x(x\notin A)$. Equivalently, $\lnot\exists x(x\in A)$.
>
> **Axiom.** There exists an empty set, denoted by $\varnothing$.

Assuming the axiom of extensionality, we can show that any two empty sets are equal, hence *the* empty set.

> **Claim.** If $A$ is a set, then $\varnothing\subseteq A$. In other words, $\forall x(x\in\varnothing\rightarrow x\in A)$. And in English, every element of the empty set is an element of $A$.

*Proof.* If $\varnothing\nsubseteq A$, then $\lnot\forall x(x\in\varnothing\rightarrow x\in A)$ is true, which means $\exists x\lnot(x\in\varnothing\rightarrow x\in A)$, and equivalently $\exists x\lnot(x\notin\varnothing\lor x\in A)$, which again translates to $\exists x(x\in\varnothing\land x\notin A)$. In particular, $x\in\varnothing$ which is a contradiction since $\lnot\exists x(x\in\varnothing)$ is the definition of the empty set. $\square$

In simpler words, the proof is saying, if this wasn't the case, you should be able to find a counterexample, which means an element of the empty set which is not an element of $A$. But there are no such elements. So the statement holds.

Once you sit to prove a few statements about sets, once you've gone through several vacuous truth sort of arguments like above, once you've meddled with sets, you'll get some picture, and what is an empty set will be clearer.

Comment: I was expecting an answer from you! :) How can a man miss it if he is an upcoming set theorist!

Comment: Well, a man has to teach, a man has a cold he cannot seem to shake off, and a man was not sure what to add to Carl's excellent answer.

Comment: TBH, this just defines `set` from `∈`, which is somewhat self-referential if you consider `x ∈ Y` as `x is an element in the set Y`. IOW, if you come from the direction of the topic starter, then "set" is a more fundamental concept than "membership of a set".

Comment: @MSalters: No, this is not "self-referential" at all. The formalist version would be to say, we have a binary relation symbol $\in$, and we have a list of axioms. Given a model of these axioms, we call the objects there "sets". But there is no "formal definition" of the term set which is any different than "an object in a universe of set theory". I agree that coming as a newbie, the objects exist before the relation does. Which is why I suggested to work formally with the definitions and axioms.

Comment: Since you've taken the existence of (an) empty set as an axiom above, it might also be worth pointing out that there's nothing fundamentally unprovable about it; i.e. that, in set theories including some form of [specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification), the existence of an empty set follows straightforwardly from the existence of *any* set.

Comment: This is a formally correct answer but doesn't match my experience as a mathematician and a mathematics teacher. For me (and for my students) the intuition has to come first. Then you codify it with a formal definition. So, paradoxically, you don't really define something until after you know what it is.

Comment: @Ethan: My experience is different. I don't know what you taught, but I can understand how in courses like combinatorics or real analysis pre-existing intuition might play a big role in understanding; since we can understand choosing from six bags or differentiation, at least on a very intuitive level. But in a course where three weeks in you already deal with infinite sets, how can you have a pre-existing intuition to the fact that $\Bbb Q$ is countable and $\Bbb R$ is not? It's uncanny. Learning how to work with formal definitions, and develop a *correct* intuition later is key.

Comment: @Ethan: My point is that with infinite and unspecified sets we *have no pre-existing intuition*. Of course I begin my first lecture by telling the students that sets are mathematical objects which serve as collections of mathematical objects themselves. But if this intuition doesn't stick, e.g. if you have troubles understanding what is the empty set, then maybe it's time to work with the formal definitions for a while, and then develop a new - and mathematically correct - intuition about sets.

Comment: I suspect that a student having trouble with set theory will not be that good at formal logic either. That's a shame because I consider the two to be fraternal twins. I would like very much to help Mr. Strand but I feel quite deeply that his problem is his inability to overcome his hobbled view of the way Mathematics works.

Comment: @Steven: For the past five years now, I've been TA'ing intro to set theory classes at least one semester of the year. So I had plenty of students. Many were freshmen and many others were not. I agree that it is not always easy to work with the logic. Even more so, when you were never fully presented to logic properly, and you have to discover the rules of the game as you play along. But if you sit down and study, slowly, carefully, in a constructed fashion one step at a time, it's quite easy to learn on a formal basis and develop the intuition. And if you're not willing to put in the effort...

Comment: ... well, if you're not willing to put in the effort, then you're on your own anyway, and I couldn't care less if you learn or not. :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes. Unless they took geometry, they were probably never exposed to logic. Even then many high schools don't teach it any more. When I taught in a high school, we had a geometry class for non college students. We didn't teach logic in that class. Guess how many of those students ended up going to the local college. Since I taught night classes there, I saw many of them.

Comment: @Steven: Since in Israel kids go through three years of army, and maybe another year or two of "relaxing from the army service" before they come to study, I can assure you that not many of them remember anything from high school. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Mathematicians don't do grammar; Or more correctly, those who are pedantic about grammar usually can't be precise about mathematics. Unfortunately you have fallen into the trap of the 'common idiom', which is defined by its inconsistencies.

You will note that the Romans didn't have the number (symbol) zero, and much of English is based on the Victorian assumption of a Latin grammar, so you are stuck with what the software coders call an 'off by one' error. No things is a number of things; that number is zero, despite the confusions of common (miss)understanding. A similar trap occurs between 'Or' and 'exclusive Or', with the English version of the former meaning the latter!

It takes a while to become comfortable with these differences and distinctions in mathematical writing.

Comment: Philip, you make a good point - namely, that mathematicians use language differently when they're speaking math, and that this is intentional - but its not phrased to my liking. I'm upvoting, but grudgingly.

Comment: I took a long time working my way through the $\delta-\epsilon$ definition of continuity. It is, in my opinion, one of the finest definitions in Mathematics. But it took me days to see how simple it was. Then I took topology and found out how much simpler continuity could be.I love how simple ideas have such amazing consequences. You need language to communicate mathematical ideas. But the words are a catalyst, not a scaffold.

Comment: @Philip I always wondered if 'Syntactic Structures' could be considered a mathematics book.

Answer (score 5):

#### The empty set (first "problem")

*The* empty set (sets are uniquely defined by their elements, so there aren't multiple "empty sets") is a mathematical primitive--a conceptual entity upon which a larger mathematical framework is built.

Mathematical primitives are notoriously difficult to define. One of Euclid's definitions of a "point" is "that which has no part"; one of my math textbooks snarkily asked "could this not also apply to an out-of-work actor?" Similarly, a "number" can usually be thought of as "how many of something" there is, but in that sense, the number "zero" represents "none of something," which is "weird" in the same way that "a collection of *no objects*" is "weird."

With that said, there are a few ways of trying to conceptualize the empty set:

- The aforementioned "grocery bag" analogy is pretty good, because it shows that the fact that sets are *defined by* the fact that they can have mathematical "objects" in them is *distinct* from the fact that not all sets actually *have* a non-zero number of objects in them. You can go a little bit further with this: just as you can remove items from a grocery bag until it is empty, you can imagine *subtracting* a set from itself, i.e., creating a new set with *none* of the items from the original set--and of course this is still a set, because what else could it be?
- Somewhat similarly, but without the analogy, consider the *intersection* set operation on two *disjoint* sets. Sets are *disjoint* when they contain no common elements, e.g. `{A,B}` and `{C,D}`, and the *intersection* of two sets is the *set* of common elements. E.g., for `{A,B}` and `{B,C}`, the intersection is the set `{B}`. But for `{A,B}`, and `{C,D}`, the intersection is, of course, the set `{}`.
- Even if the intersection operation doesn't make intuitive sense to you when there are no elements left in the resulting set, you can consider all set operations to be merely text-operations based on grammatical rules. (This is a highly formalized and well-developed branch of math that ultimately underpins much of computer science, but I'll try to be fairly non-technical.) Consider a text-based representation of sets wherein the pair of symbols `{` and `}` denote a *set*, and the symbol `,` separates each set *member* from the next. You don't need to "understand" what this "means" in a philosophical sense in order to recognize that, for instance, `{A}` is a set containing the single element `A`, and `{A}}` is an ill-formed (i.e. invalid) textual representation in this scheme ("scheme" here is a non-technical word; the correct word is "grammar"). In other words, `{A}}` doesn't mean anything; it doesn't represent a set, because `}` must *always* be paired with `{`. (Note that I was implicitly using this grammar in the previous bullet point without needing to explain it; it is, of course, fairly intuitive.) Now, is `{}` a valid set in this grammar? The answer is *yes*, because the braces are correctly paired. What elements are contained by `{}`? There aren't any.
- The formal set-theoretic way of defining sets is actually to *start with* the empty set, define set operations, and permit *including* sets within other sets (i.e. state that for every set `S`, `{S}` is also a set). Here, there is no possibility of the existence of `{}` contradicting the definition of the word "set", since our definition of "set" starts with the words "`{}` is a set."

#### Subsets (second "problem")

You seem to be getting the wrong impression from the word "subset". The sentence "A is a subset of B" does *not* imply either of the following:

- A is "smaller than" B (i.e. has fewer members)

  - Sometimes the phrase "proper subset" is used to indicate a set that is "smaller than" the superset: i.e., if A is a *proper* subset of B, then there exists at least one element of B that is *not* in A.
- A is a *member of* B (i.e. A is one of the "objects" in B)

All that sentence means is that, for every "object" that is in A, it is *also* in B. There are two easy ("trivial") ways for this to be true:

- A *is* B. That is, they contain exactly the same elements. If A *is* B, then is it possible for A to contain something that B does not? No, of course not. Thus A is a subset of B.
- A has no elements. If A has no elements, then does it have any elements that are not in B? No, because it does not have any elements, *period*.

The second bullet point, obviously, is why the empty set is a subset of all sets. The first bullet point is the special case describing the fact that `{}` is a subset of *itself*. Here, where A is `{}` and B is *also* `{}`, it is both true that A has no elements (and therefore has no elements that are not also in B) and A and B contain exactly the same elements (i.e., neither contains any elements). Thus, trivially, "all elements" in A (all none of them!) are also in B.

If it confuses you that statements are considered "true" when they don't actually describe anything, consider the following statement: "All unicorns lack horns." Instead of asking why this is or isn't true, consider how it could possibly be *false*. If it were false, then at least one unicorn would have a horn. But no unicorn actually exists, and so there are no unicorns that actually have horns! Thus the statement cannot be false. Similarly, it is *also* true that "all unicorns *have* horns", because we are simply making blanket claims about *nothing*. There are no unicorns that *lack* horns, so all unicorns have horns.

#### Containing something and nothing (third "problem")

This is really just more discussion about the concept of subsets. Once again, *is a subset of* does not mean *is a member of*.

Consider a set S described as `{A,B,C}` (i.e. its *members* are A, B, and C, whatever those are).

It "possesses something," in your words, because it "possesses" (i.e. "has members") A, B, and C. Now, does it make sense to say that it "possesses nothing"? Well, maybe, but that's incredibly vague terminology, so let's go back to what's actually being claimed: "the null set is a subset of all sets, and therefore the null set is a subset of S."

Does this mean that the null set is a *member of* the set S? No, because S's members are A, B, and C, and as far as we know, none of those are the null set.

But it does mean that S has within it every member of the null set. (This is just the "inverted" way of saying that all members of the null set are also members of S.) In other words, there are *no* members of the null set that are *not* members of S. How do we know this? Because there are *no* members of the null set... *period*.

Now, what if S *did* contain the null set? What would that look like? Well, then we would have S described by `{A, B, C, {}}`. (Ignore spaces; they don't mean anything.) Now, `{}` is still a subset of S, because, again, `{}` has no members that aren't also in S. But now, `{}` itself is also a *member of* S. This might seem a bit weird at first, but remember that sets aren't collections of "objects" in the grocery-bag sense of "containing" physical objects; they're collections of *mathematical entities* or *concepts*. (Even integers are "mathematical concepts" rather than physical realities; what is the *physical* reality of, say, the number 3?) `{}`, as established, is a mathematical entity; it has a definition and a meaning. So the set `{A, B, C, {}}` isn't any "weirder" than the set `{A, B, C, 0}` or the set `{A, B, C, (0,0)}` where `(0,0)` represents the origin-point of a Cartesian coordinate system.

Comment: (+1) for "clearly" highlighting all the terminology issues and resolving them!! (I know I'm "a bit" late.)

Answer (score 3):

There are some issues with the intuitive definition of a set which you have taken as the basis for your understanding.

It is possible to say "a set is a well-defined collection of objects". What do we mean by "well-defined"? - Well that is the whole question of the foundations of set theory. In studying the question, mathematicians have found it necessary to have some control over the nature of the "objects" in the "collection" - as always with mathematical definitions, we have to be absolutely precise. So mathematics proceeds by building standard sets as a model.

Set theory thus provides a model of standard sets. We can then talk about general sets as being collections which can be put in $1-1$ correspondence with one of the standard sets. We have to get the "objects" of our "collections" from somewhere, as well as language for talking about them - the elements of a group, or the vertices of a graph, or the letters of an alphabet for example. For the set theory model to work, the language we use of our objects has to be compatible with the language we use about sets in the model. Otherwise we need a different model.

Suppose we are solving equations. We may want to talk about the properties of the solutions before we know what the solutions are. Indeed, we may eventually discover that there are no solutions. So we want our model to be sufficiently flexible to deal with this case - and the empty set does the job, we don't have to put a caveat in every sentence. And that's just one example. It is just very convenient to have the empty set as part of the model.

To go back to the equations, we may prove at an early stage that any solution is a positive real number, and use this to derive a contradiction (so there are no solutions). The empty set validates the statement "any solution is a positive real number" and makes it mathematically viable.

Comment: When you say "standard set" do you mean an element of the von Neumann universe $V$ that is built up inductively from $\emptyset$ by repeated application of the power set operation (and taking unions at limit stages)?  In most set theories, such as $\mathsf{ZFC}$, *everything* is a standard set in this sense.  (There are alternative set theories with urelements but I'm not sure if this is related to your point.)

Comment: In any case, I think it's a bit misleading to say that set theory is used to formalize mathematics by taking a model consisting of standard sets and then finding bijections between collections outside the model and sets inside the model.  Where would the bijections themselves live, and how would we reason about them?  The usual way to use set theory to formalize mathematics is to adopt the axioms of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (which means making the tacit assumption that every object is a set) and then to define real numbers, functions, manifolds *etc.* as objects (sets) satisfying certain properties.

Comment: @TrevorWilson But we can talk about sets of shoes and socks and "collections" of physical objects. In this context set theory is definitely a model rather than the reality. I deliberately didn't say we formalise mathematics within set theory, and I said we need "language" to talk about things - and that would include "bijections", though that was not explicit. It was tempting to write more fully about foundational issues, but that did not seem to be consistent with the level of existing knowledge shown by OP. It will be useful to OP to know that the issues run deeper. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Ah, I think I was taking "model" and "1 − 1 correspondence" more literally than you intended.

Answer (score 3):

People used to argue that $0$ wasn't a number for reasons very much like your arguements about the empty set.

Forget about defining sets. The most important thing about sets is this.

If x is an object and S is a set, then either $x\in S$ is true or $x \notin S$ is true; but never both.

When people say that no element is a member of the empty set they are just, badly, trying to say that $x \in \varnothing$ is always false and $x \notin \varnothing$ is always true.

There is a very basic connection between sets and logic. Learning set theory will help you use and understand logic and vice versa.

It's also very convenient to have an empty set. For example.

- If we want to say that sets A and B have no elements in common, then
  we can say that their intersection is the empty set.
- If we want to say that an equation has no solution, then we can say
  that the solution set is empty.

There is no nice way to put this. You are confused because you refuse to change your ideas about the way mathematics works. I am very good at mathematics and I have had that same problem more than once. If you are lucky, someone will explain it so that things in your head click into place. If not, which is the more probable thing, you are going to have to work this out yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Set is actually a 'well-defined' collection of objects. Here the adjective well-defined means, such a definition using which, for every element in contention for being element of a set, we can definitively say whether that element belongs to the set or not.

You could ask the same question for 0 - how come zero is a number? The answer is it wasn't for a long time until Brahmagupta decided to make it one. How did he do that? He defined operations of addition, subtraction, and multiplication on zero as they were defined for other numbers. He also extended usual attributes of associativity, distributivity, commutativity etc. And now zero is essential, especially since it serves as the identity element for addition on whole numbers.

Similarly null set is the identity element for the union operation among sets. So, null set is a set as much as zero is a number.

Comment: Never mind zero: for the longest time western mathematicians disputed whether or not _one_ is a number! Euclid defined a "number" as a _multitude_ of units, so 2 would be the smallest number, and it was not until the late 1500s (almost two thousand years later) that consensus finally seemed to come down on the side of 1 being a number.

Comment: Also, "well-defined collection of objects" doesn't work as a definition of what is or isn't a set. That still leads to nonsensical results, such as the Buralli-Forti paradox (the collection of all possible order types of well-orders cannot be allowed to be a set).

Comment: @HenningMakholm: And then it repeated again with $\sqrt{-1}$. For quite a while it existed only in the imagination. Even today, some people think that all mathematics exists only in the mind...

Comment: Look at some of the adjectives used to describe numbers. Negative, Odd, Imaginary, Complex, Irrational... I like to think that a number that isn't a surd, is an absurd number.