# Is the word "empty" in set theory different from the word "empty" in ordinary language?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I skimmed over this question [Is the empty set a subset of itself?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334666/is-the-empty-set-a-subset-of-itself), and I'm currently under the impression that it's a widespread belief that the empty set contains itself. But a contradiction seems to arise: if the empty set contains itself, then it's NOT empty. After all, if we call a set non-empty just because it contains the empty set, then why should we treat the empty set itself differently?

Then it occurred to me that maybe mathematicians define "empty" differently in set theory. Maybe by "empty set" they mean a "set that contains only itself", instead of a "set that contains absolutely nothing".

Is my surmise correct?

Comment: "Contains" is an ambiguous word that people should stop using with regard to sets.

Comment: "contained" $\in$ is different (in set theory) from "contained" $\subseteq$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA If the only type of objects that we can have is sets, then what is the difference? Every element would be a subset.

Comment: **NO**. The basic relation between sets is : $A \in B$. Empty set is **defined** as the set satisfying the formula : $\exists E \ \forall x \ \lnot (x \in E)$.

Comment: Subset is defined as : $A \subseteq B \leftrightarrow \forall x \ (x \in A \to x \in B)$.

Comment: Mixing together the two def, we can easily verify that $\emptyset \subseteq \emptyset$. But $\emptyset$ is empty, i.e. for no $x$ we have that $x \in \emptyset$. Thus, we must have $\emptyset \notin \emptyset$.

Comment: Math is made of axiom, definitions and logic; sometimes they contradict our intuition.

Comment: In conclusion, "empty" means empty in set theory as well as in natural language. It is the locution ["is contained into"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contain) that bifurcates in set theory into: to be element of, and to be part of.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  I wonder, how it could look like for a set to contain set {1} (for example)  as its element? And would be it possible for {1} to be an element without being a subset?

Comment: Not clear...  $1 \in \{ 1 \}$ and $\{ 1 \} \subseteq \{ 1 \}$. *Subset* as defined above is **not** proper subset. Thus $\emptyset \subseteq$ \emptyset$ but the emptyset is **not** a *proper* subset of itself.

Comment: The set $\{\{1\}\}$ has $\{1\}$ as an element, but not as a subset. The set $\{1\}$ has $1$ as an element, but not as a subset, it also has $\{1\}$ as a subset, but not as an element.

Comment: You van see the very very very similar post : [How is an empty set truly empty ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1416441/how-is-an-empty-set-truly-empty)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you are confusing two possible meanings of "contains". Often we say $A$ contains $B$ to mean $B$ is an element of $A$ (but see below). In this sense, $\varnothing$ doesn't contain itself, because it has no elements. (Also, no set is an element of itself.)

However, $\varnothing$ is a subset of itself, because it doesn't contain any elements outside itself. By the same logic, every set is a subset of itself.

To see the distinction in non-empty sets, $\{1\}$ is a subset of $\{1,2\}$ but $\{1,2\}$ does not contain $\{1\}$. It does contain $1$, but that is not the same thing.

---

On the usage of "contains", [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_(mathematics)) says:

> The expressions "A includes x" and "A contains x" are also used to mean set membership, however some authors use them to mean instead "x is a subset of A". Logician George Boolos strongly urged that "contains" be used for membership only and "includes" for the subset relation only.

Comment: "It does contain 1, but that is not the same thing." I wonder, how  it could look like to a set contain set {1} as element? And would be it possible for {1} to be an element without being a subset?

Comment: Sure, the power set (set of all subsets) of $\{1,2\}$ is $P=\{\{1,2\},\{1\},\{2\},\varnothing\}$. So $\{1\}\in P$, but $1\not\in P$, meaning that $\{1\}\not\subset P$.

Comment: The opening paragraph has the contains relationship backwards.

Comment: @jaxad0127 thanks!

Comment: @EspeciallyLime Can you rigorously prove that {1} is NOT an element of {1,2}?

Comment: @user161005: By definition something is an element of $\{1,2\}$ if and only if it equals $1$ or it equals $2$. We cannot have $\{1\}=1$ due to the Axiom of Regularity. Whether $\{1\}=2$ depends on your definition of "$2$". One convention that has been proposed in the past is that $2$ does indeed mean $\{1\}$, but for the last many decades it has been nearly universal to define $2$ to mean $\{0,1\}$. In that case $\{1\}=2$ is false because $0\in 2$ but $0\notin\{1\}$. Therefore, $\{1\}\notin\{1,2\}$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I feel like the whole "numbers are really sets" thing makes everything even more confusing for beginners asking questions like "why is $\emptyset \subseteq \emptyset$?"

Answer (score 9):

The problem here is you are using the word "contains" for two different things:

- When $x$ is an element of a set $A$, we write $x\in A$ and sometimes say "$A$ contains $x$".
- When $B$ is a subset of $A$, we write $B\subseteq A$ and also sometimes say "$A$ contains $B$".

This is a common problem and usually we can determine from the context whether which of the two types of containment is being referred to.

With the empty set, it is always false that $x\in\varnothing$, i.e., the empty set does not have elements, it is *empty*.

However, it has a subset: $\varnothing\subseteq\varnothing$ is true. Why is that? Well, $B\subseteq A$ means that whenever $x$ is an element of $B$ it also is an element of $A$, or in other words, $A$ contains (as elements) at least all elements of $B$. In particular $\varnothing\subseteq X$ is true for *any* set $X$, since there are no elements in $\varnothing$ that have to be contained in $X$ at all.

Answer (score 3):

$A\subseteq B$ is not the same as $A\in B$. The former one says that all elements of $A$ are also in $B$. Whereas the latter one means the set $A$ is an element of $B$. So $B=\{\,A,\dots\,\}$.

Therefore it is correct to say $\emptyset\subseteq\emptyset$ but not $\emptyset\in\emptyset$ since the empty set has no elements.

Comment: Along with the ambiguity of "contains", I really wish people would stop using $\subset$ to mean $\subseteq$. Nobody would ever write $<$ to mean $\leq$ so why do we do it with sets?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thank you. I have changed it. In university we have used $\subset$ and $\subsetneq$ so far.