# Why $|\{\emptyset \}| =1$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In set theory cardinality of empty set is 0 but How the cardinality of $|\{\emptyset\}| $ is $1$ ? Well one can say $\emptyset$ is an element here but $\emptyset$ set has no elements in it so when it enclosed in a curly bracket how the new set has an element now as the enclosed set has no element?

Comment: There are two commands for the empty set: \emptyset and \varemptyset

Comment: Why would it matter that $\varnothing$ has no members? You're counting the members of $\{\varnothing\}$, not the members of its members.

Comment: $\{\emptyset\}$ is the set that has one element in it - the empty set. It is a set of sets, just like $|\{\{1,2\}\}|=1,$ not $2$.

Comment: @ajotatxe :  You mean \varnothing not \varemptyset

Comment: You are mixing up mereological sums and sets of ZFC. It is interesting.

Comment: Do not forget that the "*depth*" here matters.  $\emptyset\neq \{\emptyset\}$ and is further different than $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$.  These are all different objects.  For some reason early students might think that you can remove some of these outer braces and not affect things but that is wholly untrue, it affects it very much.

Comment: See also the post [What is an empty set ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1255726/what-is-an-empty-set)

Comment: @JMoravitz. Thanks for the details . I was thinking that. You said if we remove some of these outer braces it will affect the set but I still don't understand how ?

Comment: Consider an analogy of sports teams.  The Astros and the Nationals are playing in the world series.  Now, the Astros happen to have several players like Justin Verlander, Zack Greinke and so on...  We could have thought of it as Astros = {Justin, Zack, ... } and similarly Nationals as {Raudy, Victor, ...}.  Now, I want to talk about the *teams* of who is playing in the world series right now.  That would be $\{\text{Astros}, \text{Nationals}\}$.  There are only two *teams* who are playing.  I am not interested right now in talking about the number of players, I am only interested in teams

Comment: Sure, if I wanted to, I *could* talk about the number of players, but that is an entirely different question.  Now, if your complaint is about the set containing the emptyset as not having any "content" deep inside of it, however deep, that is irrelevant to the point.  Consider another analogy of Christmas decorations.  Some people put empty wrapped boxes underneath of the tree so that it looks pretty.  That doesn't mean that the boxes aren't there.  If we ask how many boxes are under the tree, even the empty ones should count.

Answer (score 3):

Think of $\emptyset$ as an empty box.

Think of $\{\emptyset\}$ as a box with an empty box inside. The outer box has one thing.